# Ordered hibernate relationships

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I have two entities, Books and Wishlist. My wish list contains books. I want to get the collection of books that are in my wish list ordered in the same order they were added to the wish list.

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "WISHLISTS_BOOKS", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "BOOK_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "WISHLIST_ID") })
private Set<Book> books;
```

This is where I get stuck. There's an `@OrderBy` annotation but from what I understand it refers to a field in the book to use to order by. In my case, since a book can belong to multiple wish lists, I can't do that. Instead, I tried to create a `added_ts` timestamp field in the WISHLISTS_BOOKS join table but I'm not sure how to refer to it.

Can anyone help me sort this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use @OrderColumn(name = "added_ts") to achieve ordering.

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "WISHLISTS_BOOKS", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "BOOK_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "WISHLIST_ID") })
@OrderColumn(name = "added_ts")
private Set<Book> books;
```

Comment: That's perfect. Let me on the right path. http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Order_Column_.28JPA_2.0.29. Thank you